# Invoke Blackberry Messenger via the RIM API

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, bb-messenger

I want to incorporate a light contacts invitation module into my application using the Blackberry Messenger.

Is there an API that can invoke the BBM and allow the user to select contacts to send a pre-filled( pre-generated ) text to?

The target JDE is 4.5 upwards!

Comment: Did you get any sucess so far. Please let me know?

Answer (score 1):

`net.rim.blackberry.api.blackberrymessenger` API is the relevant class to access the required attributes and methods to invoke BBM.

If you look into `net.rim.blackberry.api.blackberrymessenger.BlackBerryMessenger`, then you can use chooseContact() and getContactInfo() methods for your desired requirements.